# How to pass an event to ClientValidationFunction of asp:CustomValidator?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox, webforms

I have to check target, causing web form validation, is there any way to do this in a crossbrowser way without accessing window.event ? It's unavailable in FF.

```
script type="text/javascript">
    function myValidate(source, args)
    {
      var id = window.event.target.id;
      if( id == "Button1")
      alert('a');
      else if(id == "Name")
      alert('b');
    }
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="myValidate();" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator"></asp:CustomValidator>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Name"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
</div>
</form>
```

For now I see two ways:

1. override entire chain of WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions, Page_ClientValidate, ValidatorValidate, CustomValidatorEvaluateIsValid
2. save target in window.target in custom onclick functions, but it is unreliable, because there may be tons of form submitters and window.target will not "unsave" itself